# Process monitor on windows server 2003

Tags: windows-server-2003, process-monitoring

We have a third party vendor running a program/service on my servers. We need to monitor that process and see if that process is using a lot of memory or dumping/uploading lot of data or accessing any other process/stuff that it is supposed not to access.

What is the best possible way to do this? Since it is a prod box, we are not supposed to install any software on the server. So, any default tools (like Regmon/Filemon) that comes with Win 2003 would be great. But, if there is no tools that can help, I can get persmissions to install s/w.

**tldr**; need to keep an eye on a process using default windows tools. What is the best way??

Any help/pointers is greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As a first **regmon** and **filemon** does not comes with any windows version neither desktop nor server edition.

It is product of sysinternals (M. Rusenovich) currently are covered by MS, but not bundled in any version of OS.

Standard tools are called performance counters and are available through manage computer  context menu on "My Computer" icon, or just by running **perfmon.exe** or perfmon.msc

You can setup exact what you want to track.